# C++ vector input through a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to add multiple strings into a vector through a for loop, I can do this easily with an array but I am having trouble doing the same on a vector. Below is an example of the array I would like to try to convert into a vector.

**Array Style**

```
String StudentNames[];
int StudentNumbers;
for(int i = 0; StudentNumbers > i; i++){
cin >> StudentNames[i];
}
```

**Vector Style**

```
vector<string> StudentNames;
int StudentNumbers;
//How do i add a for loop using vector and add strings to it similar to the array above?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) as :-

```
std::string sn; //temporary string

for(int i = 0; StudentNumbers > i; i++){
std::getline(std::cin, sn); 

StudentNames.push_back(sn); 
}
```

And then you can access ith name as `StudentNames[i]`

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create the vector with the right size for the loop:

```
int StudentNumbers = ....;
std::vector<std::string> studentNames(StudentNumbers);
for(auto it = studentNames.begin(), end = studentNames.end(); it != end; ++it){
  std::cin >> *it;
}
```

or

```
int StudentNumbers = ....;
std::vector<std::string> studentNames(StudentNumbers);
for(auto& s = 0; studentNames){
  std::cin >> s;
}
```